# How can I combine an integer setter and a binding setter into a class that I can use in XAML and C# also?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two classes that look like this:

```
public class Spacer1 : BoxView
{
    public Spacer1(int Height)
    {
        HeightRequest = Height;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Margin = 0;
    }
}

public class Spacer2 : BoxView
{
    public Spacer2()
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Margin = 0;
        this.SetDynamicResource(HeightRequestProperty, "DefaultSpacerHeight");
    }
}
```

Is there some way that I can combine these into one class so I can still call in my XAML code something like this:

```
<Spacer HeightRequest="10" />
```

or in C#

```
var a = new Spacer(10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# allows you to [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading) methods and constructors

```
public class Spacer : BoxView
{
    public Spacer()
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Margin = 0;
        this.SetDynamicResource(HeightRequestProperty, "DefaultSpacerHeight");
    }

    public Spacer(int Height)
    {
        HeightRequest = Height;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Margin = 0;
    }
}
```